# Mapping an array of objects to dictionary in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I am trying to map array of objects to dictionary using typescript.
I have written the following code:

```
let data = [
  {id: 1, country: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
  {id: 2, country: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
  {id: 3, country: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.assign({}, ...data.map((x) => ({[x.id]: x.country})));
```

I am getting output as below:

```
{1: "Germany", 2: "Austria", 3: "Switzerland"}
```

I want to get population in the output as well and for that i am making the following code change but it is giving syntax error:

```
let dictionary = Object.assign({}, ...data.map((x) => ({[x.id]: x.country, x.population})));
```

Desired output is similar to below:

```
{
  "1": {
    "country": "Germany",
    "population": 83623528
  },
  "2": {
    "country": "Austria",
    "population": 8975552
  },
  "3": {
    "country": "Switzerland",
    "population": 8616571
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output ? - the one you pasted is not a valid javascript object

Comment: You're missing a key, and expected output is not a valid object

Comment: Your `Desired output` as mentioned in the question is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Object.fromEntries` (assuming your value needs to be an object to preserve both `country` and `population`):

```js
let data = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
    {id: 2, country: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
    {id: 3, country: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({id,...rest})=> ([id, rest]) ));

console.log(dictionary);
```

or in case you want to return an array with no keys:

```js
let data = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
    {id: 2, country: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
    {id: 3, country: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({id,...rest})=> ([id, Object.values(rest)]) ));

console.log(dictionary);
```

Comment: I am getting an error `TS2339: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are hopping something like this:

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, country: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
  {id: 2, country: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
  {id: 3, country: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.fromEntries(data.map(item => [item.id, {country: item.country, population: item.population}]));

console.log(dictionary);
```

Comment: The `id` is missing here. For every `id` there is a `country` and `population`

Comment: Check it now. Is it the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you need to build a object for `id`, and use rest parameter

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, country: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
  {id: 2, country: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
  {id: 3, country: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({
  id,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  [id]: rest
})));

console.log(dictionary)
```